# Conditional Probability of Biased Coin Toss

Tags: probability

I am currently self-teaching myself probability because through MIT opencourse ware because my teacher merely reiterates the textbook in an even more complicated way.
In Lecture 3.6, the instructor presents the following problem (I have screenshotted it). I understand how the law of total probability was employed to derive the probability of getting H on the 11th toss. However, the teacher does not provide a rigorous explanation of how to derive P(toss 11 = H| first 10 tosses are heads).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $~E_1~$ denote the event that 10 consecutive heads were tossed.

Let $~E_2~$ denote the event that the coin A was used.

Then

$$p(E_2 ~| ~E_1) = \frac{p(E_1 \cap E_2)}{p(E_1)}$$

$$= \frac{p(E_1 \cap E_2)}{p(E_1 \cap E_2) + p(E_1 \cap [\neg E_2] ~)}.$$

$p(E_1 \cap E_2) = (0.5) \times (0.9)^{10}.$ 
$p(E_1 \cap [\neg E_2] ~) = (0.5) \times (0.1)^{10}.$

Let $~\displaystyle R = \frac{0.5}{0.5} \times \frac{(0.9)^{10}}{(0.9)^{10} + (0.1)^{10}}, ~S = 1 - R.$

Then $~R~$ equals the probability that coin A was used and $~S~$ equals the probability that coin B was used.

So, the probability that the 11th-toss is Heads will equal

$$[R \times (0.9)] + [S \times (0.1)].$$

Comment: I don't really follow. You use E2 to denote the event that coin A was used, but here E2 should be the event that the 11th toss comes up heads, which could occur with either coin A or coin B.

Comment: @oatmilkunicorn No, first you have to calculate the probability that Coin A was used.  This is why I used $~E_2~$ to denote the event that Coin A was used.  Once that is calculated, then, as shown at the end of my answer, it is straightforward to compute the probability that the 11-th toss will be a Heads.

Comment: @oatmilkunicorn Do you agree that I have correctly calculated the probability that Coin A was used, for the first $~10~$ coin flips?  If so, is there some specific step, anywhere in the analysis that you think is invalid, inaccurate, or confusing?

Comment: No, I guess instinctually I would approach the problem differently (my instincts for probability aren't very strong). My issue is that for the numerator, I thought you could convert P(11H intersect 10H) to P(11H) + P(10H) and then use the law of total probability to solve? It would end up being 0.5 [(0.9)^11 + (0.1)^11 + (0.9)^10 + (0.1)^10 ]. But the problem is that you end up with an extra '+1' that you dont need when you divide by P(H10). I just dont see where I went wrong though in my reasoning

Comment: @oatmilkunicorn  In order for me, or anyone else, to find the mistake in your analysis, you will need to overhaul your original posting, using [Mathjax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  Try to make your math very clear and well organized, with plenty of line breaks, paragraph breaks, and section dividers.  If you are using a theorem (e.g. law of total probability), provide an online link or describe the theorem in detail, so that the reviewer can tell where you went wrong.  Use `<br>` for line breaks, and use `-----` for section dividers.

Comment: @oatmilkunicorn After you edit your posting, if you are still confused where you went wrong, and no other reviewer steps up, leave me another *flagging comment*, following this answer, and I will look at your work.

Comment: Sorry, I think I just figured out a much simpler way to solve it. I am in a rush so I didn't use math jax but it is pretty straightforward to understand. I posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out a way to solve this:

Using Bayes rule, you get P(H11)P(H10|H11) / P(H10).
The probability of getting 10 heads given that you get 11 heads is just 1. P(H11) = 0.5[0.9^(11) + 0.1^(11)]. The denominator is just 0.5[0.9^(10) + 0.1^(10)]. When you divide these out you get 0.89, approx 0.9.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).